# VB.NET Application does not fully close

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, terminate

When I launch my application, and press the "X" button on my app, or my quit button which deploys: me.close   It will not fully close the application. Like the instance is still running in Visual Studio or if you go to task manager processes you can still see it there. How would I get this to fully close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is that you have some threads apart from the main thread running, and those aren't background threads. In general, try debugging it: attach to it from VS, and use Pause button to break it, and look at what threads are there, and what they are doing.

Comment: I mean is there a quick and easy way to fix this, by ending the whole process instead of going through all that digging?

Comment: The only way to fix it is to find out what's wrong. If you have some thread still running, then terminating the process disregarding this thread can lead to data loss (e.g. what if it was writing to a file at that point) and other nasty side effects. That said, if what you want is a _hack_ rather than fix, then `Environment.Exit()` on main thread will shut down all running threads and then the process.

Answer (score 6):

If you do have thread(s) running within the app, set `IsBackground` property as `True`.

[Thread.IsBackground Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx) on MSDN

> **Remarks**
>
> A thread is either a background thread
>   or a foreground thread. Background
>   threads are identical to foreground
>   threads, except that background
>   threads do not prevent a process from
>   terminating. Once all foreground
>   threads belonging to a process have
>   terminated, the common language
>   runtime ends the process. Any
>   remaining background threads are
>   stopped and do not complete.

Answer (score 2):

The "End" keyword is what you're looking for.

Put it in the FormClosed event.